# How can I use bulkuploader to populate class with a db.SelfReferenceProperty?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, bulkloader

I've got a class that is using `db.SelfReferenceProperty` to create a tree-like structure.

When trying to populate the database using `appcfg.py upload_data -- config_file=bulkloader.yaml --kind=Group --filename=group.csv (...)`
, I'm getting an exception saying `BadValueError: name must not be empty`. <sup>(Full stack below)</sup>

I tried ordering the data to make sure that a Groups that had a foreign key pointing at them were first. That didn't work.

By commenting from the bulkloader.yaml the line making the transformation "import_transform: transform.create_foreign_key('Group')", the data is uploaded, but it stores that property as string, breaking my application logic.

```
- kind: Group
  connector: csv
  connector_options:
  property_map:
    - property: __key__
      external_name: key
      export_transform: transform.key_id_or_name_as_string

    - property: name
      external_name: name
      # Type: String Stats: 9 properties of this type in this kind.

    - property: section
      external_name: section
      # Type: Key Stats: 6 properties of this type in this kind.
      import_transform: transform.create_foreign_key('Group')
      export_transform: transform.key_id_or_name_as_string
```

Is there any way to make the bulkloader take into account selfreferences, or should I either make a transformation serverside of the bulkloaded data or implement my own bulk loading algorithm?

```
----
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/username/src/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/adaptive_thread_pool.py", line 150, in WorkOnItems
    status, instruction = item.PerformWork(self.__thread_pool)
  File "/home/username/src/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/bulkloader.py", line 691, in PerformWork
    transfer_time = self._TransferItem(thread_pool)
  File "/home/username/src/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/bulkloader.py", line 846, in _TransferItem
    self.content = self.request_manager.EncodeContent(self.rows)
  File "/home/username/src/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/bulkloader.py", line 1267, in EncodeContent
    entity = loader.create_entity(values, key_name=key, parent=parent)
  File "/home/username/src/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/bulkload/bulkloader_config.py", line 382, in create_entity
    return self.dict_to_entity(input_dict, self.bulkload_state)
  File "/home/username/src/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/bulkload/bulkloader_config.py", line 133, in dict_to_entity
    self.__run_import_transforms(input_dict, instance, bulkload_state_copy)
  File "/home/username/src/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/bulkload/bulkloader_config.py", line 230, in __run_import_transforms
    value = self.__dict_to_prop(transform, input_dict, bulkload_state)
  File "/home/username/src/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/bulkload/bulkloader_config.py", line 188, in __dict_to_prop
    value = transform.import_transform(value)
  File "/home/username/src/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/bulkload/bulkloader_parser.py", line 93, in __call__
    return self.method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/username/src/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/bulkload/transform.py", line 114, in generate_foreign_key_lambda
        return datastore.Key.from_path(kind, value)
  File "/home/username/src/google_appengine/google/appengine/api/datastore_types.py", line 384, in from_path
    ValidateString(id_or_name, 'name')
  File "/home/username/src/google_appengine/google/appengine/api/datastore_types.py", line 109, in ValidateString
    raise exception('%s must not be empty.' % name)
BadValueError: name must not be empty.
```

Comment: Actually, poking around with the interactive console, I can't even get the individual objects, the objects are foobared. I get a `AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'has_key'` exception.

Answer (score 4):

Using [an answer given to a similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3148352/need-help-creating-gae-datastore-loader-class/3590603#3590603) as a base, I could successfully solve this by creating a small `helpers.py` file to do act as a wrapper around `transform.create_foreign_key`:

```
from google.appengine.api import datastore

def create_foreign_key(kind, key_is_id=False):
  def generate_foreign_key_lambda(value):
    if value is None:
      return None

    if key_is_id:
      value = int(value)
    try:
      return datastore.Key.from_path(kind, value)
    except:
      return None

  return generate_foreign_key_lambda
```

Once that file is in place in the same directory as your yaml bolk upload configuration file (`bulkloader.yaml`), you add this to that file:

```
python_preamble:
- (...)
- import: helpers

transformers:

- kind: Group
  connector: csv
  connector_options:
  property_map:
    - property: __key__
      external_name: key
      export_transform: transform.key_id_or_name_as_string

    - property: name
      external_name: name

    - property: section
      external_name: section
      import_transform: helpers.create_foreign_key('Group')
                      # ^^^^^^^ we use the wrapper instead
      export_transform: transform.key_id_or_name_as_string
```

With those changes, the bulk upload is now working correctly.

Before using this, you should definitely modify the catch all `except`, and replace it with may be `except BadValueError`.

Answer (score 2):

`transform.py` (maybe only recently) contains a decorator that solves this issue:

```
def none_if_empty(fn):
  """A decorator which returns None if its input is empty else fn(x).

  Useful on import.  Can be used in config files
  (e.g. "transform.none_if_empty(int)" or as a decorator.

  Args:
    fn: Single argument transform function.

  Returns:
    Wrapped function.
  """

  def wrapper(value):


    if value == '' or value is None or value == []:
      return None
    return fn(value)

  return wrapper
```

So using the following will also solve the problem, without the introduction of a custom `helpers.py` file:

```
transform.none_if_empty(transform.create_foreign_key('Group'))
```